# why new double[26] has 224 elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Looks like a very dumb question:
Here is how an array pointer is declared:

```
double * y = new double[26];
```

After this declaration, I watched y when the program was running, and here is what I have seen:

```
name    value
y[224] 8.691694942331e-310#DEN
y[225] CXX0030: Error: Expression cannot be evaluated
```

So I am wondering why a double array declared with 26 length has 224 elements? Thanks.

Edit:
But I tried this code, and it went through!

```
int nPt = 26;
double * y = new double[nPt];
y[224] = 0;
```

If there is no y[224], how it is possible its value is assigned?

Comment: `y` only has 26 elements.

Comment: Then why there is y[224]?

Comment: It is just whatever happens to be in that memory location.

Comment: @NickTsui: There isn't. There's just nothing to stop you indexing past the end of an array and getting undefined behaviour.

Comment: Then why y[225] is not available?

Comment: @NickTsui, Undefined behaviour. There's no point in pondering over it.

Comment: Why do you guys have to downvote this thread? Asking questions is something wrong here?

Comment: @NickTsui the question is being downvoted because the exact same question has been asked 3492054 times before.

Comment: @SethCarnegie So you never asked anything that already has an answer in this world?

Comment: @NickTsui what I have done is irrelevant. I didn't downvote the question, others did. You'd have to take it up with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you allocate memory, using `new double[26]`, the system will get give your application a chunk of memory that has space for at least 26 x sizeof(double). The allocation function will indeed store the number 26 (or something that makes it possible to get the number 26 back in some other way) in some place inside it's meta-data for the memory allocation.

However, the debugger won't be able to "figure out" that the number of elements is 26, it simply knows that this is a pointer to some `double` values. When you ask to seem more than 26, you are in "undefined behaviour" land - anything can and possibly WILL happen. Including that it appears perfectly as you'd "expect" (that is, the memory is readable and contains values that can be displayed as "double". Then, when you get to element 224, the debugger can't read the memory any longer (because the OS has marked it "unavailable"). That's when it stops. It could have been 50000000 [in which case it may have taken you another few hours before you got here and asked this question...]

Right. Let's say we have a computer with 100KB of RAM, for sake of simplicity. The way the processor assigns what memory is used for what purpose is in pages of 4KB at a time. So we have 25 pages. Some of those pages are your "heap" (where `new` gets its memory). One memory allocation gets a part of such a 4KB page. Say our memory happens to be on page number 18 - 18 * 4096 = 73728 to 77823. Page 19 is marked as "not used". Our allocation within this page is 168 bytes (the first 168 bytes is used for something else) - so our address is 73896, Now, we have 26 * 8 = 208 bytes so the "Next available byte" is 73728+376 = 74104 on the page. So, y[0] has the address 73896, and we each double takes up 8 bytes. When we get to 74104 (index 26, one outside our allocated memory), we are still on page 18, it's still "available for use" according to the processor/OS. We have to go all the way to 77824 before the processor says "You can't go there". 74104 - 77824 = 3720 bytes, or 465* sizeof(double). But we are using memory we were told not to use. So, clearly in your test-case, the amount of "page left" is less than in my example.

I hope this explains it fairly well.

The reason it's 4KB is that if the processor had to keep track of EVERY single byte of memory, it would take up too much memory to track if that byte was available or not. 4KB is a good compromise between "we detect when we go outside by long enough" and "it takes up too much capacity".

Comment: But why every time it stops at 224? It does not seem random.

Comment: @NickTsui the implementation is free to do whatever it wants within the bounds of the C++ spec; it doesn't mean the results are random; if you're running the same program over and over again it's possible (but not guaranteed) that you'll get similar results, because you're allocating memory in the same way every time

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I think all your answers are right, but I can accept only one as answer. So I picked the one with most detailed explanation. Hope you understand.

Comment: It is "random" - I would be pretty surprised if you calculated where that is, it is exactly at the end of a "page" (4KB memory 'lump'), which is why it stops there. It would have stopped at exactly the same place if you had allocated an array of 220 double, etc. If you allocated 225, it would have gone on for another 4KB worth of doubles (so 512 more) and stopped at 736.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I think I assigned 26 double space for the array, and it seems the array has 225 double space. I am not quite following your explanation honestly.

Answer (score 5):

Your array only has 26 elements, and you are going beyond its bounds. That is *undefined behaviour*. The program doesn't have to crash, it just means that anything could happen. This is a bad thing and must be avoided.

Comment: In my program I was going for anything above 25; But I was curious and found this by manually type y[224] in the watch window.

Comment: I am sorry I mean I was NOT going beyond 25 in my program.

Comment: @NickTsui I got it the first time :-)

Answer (score 4):

> So I am wondering why a double array declared with 26 length has 224 elements?

It doesn't. Your debugger can't seem to figure out that `y` only has 26 elements.

> But I tried this code, and it went through!

```
int nPt = 26;
double * y = new double[nPt];
y[224] = 0;
```

The code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This doesn't mean it has to crash; it is free to fail (or not) in any way it pleases.

Comment: So this is related to what debugger I am using? I am using vs2008.

Comment: @NickTsui: Exactly. If you were to access `y[224]` in the code, you'd get undefined behaviour. The debugger is a different story since it operates outside the boundaries of C++: it just shows whatever happens to be in memory at `y + 224`.

Comment: Wait, see my update in the thread.

Comment: @NickTsui: The behaviour of the code you've added to the question is undefined. It does not have to crash. What likely happens is that it's overwriting some random memory, with unpredictable consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't exists in C/C++. In fact, an expression like t[i] is just a short cut (a syntactic sugar) to say I want to access the i-th memory location beyond address t. When you allocate a memory chunk with new and size N (new int[N]), the system gave you an address from which it is safe to access N memory location from the returned address (beware that when I said N memory location, it is not N bytes, but N*sizeof_one_element_in_bytes). But C/C++ lets you calculate any address derived from the one returned, it is up to you to ensure that you don't access bad addresses. C/C++ runtime knows nothing about arrays sizes, it can't protect you from this kind of error. C/C++ pointers are very much error-prone, you must be very careful using it. That is the price to pay to be close to the machine and/or efficient.